# How to assign XSL value in XSLT from Java Input

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In my main xml file i have 100 elements but i want only 20 elements from that xml files so i use to transform that xml using XSLT and also create my own xml file and set 20 elements with attributes by my own tag name,but now my problem is i want to select 20 elements out of 100 elements by user interface in my java servlet,so i use checkbox and make display 100 elements from that i check 20 elements it will affect my xslt sheet ,
my xml schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Staff_Detail">
      <xsl:for-each select="company/Staff">
        <xsl:element name="Staff">   // here i have to display my checked element
          <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />  // here i want to display value of the element 
        </xsl:element>        // i dont want to repeat 20 times to set element name and value
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not an XML schema but an XSLT stylesheet. Please be more careful with those terms. Besides, it is unclear what you are asking. In general, information can be passed from Java to XSLT with parameters.

Comment: sorry am new to xml please tell about xslt paramaters that i want get input from servlet and pass it to xslt sheet please help me with samples

Comment: Looks to me your XML source file(s) is/are static, but what you need is more than that; long words short, you need to manipulate or even construct XML source(s) dynamically. To start, you can read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/ and when you're capable of structuring XML, you might wanna read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/ too. I can write a working example for you to get started, but please provide a few sample data so I'll understand your data structure as well as how the expected outcome might look like.